# What is the name for that thing that lets part of the URL be an argument?

Tags: http, url-rewriting

For example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698627/ms-access-properties
```

The number is part of the URL but is an argument to the web app as opposed to other options like:

```
http://www.google.com/firefox?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official
```

where all the args come after the '`?`'. *I have used the second form before and I'm only trying to learn about the first form.*

I'm sure I can find what else I need once I known what that's called so I can Google it.

Answer (score 5):

[URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting), generally.

Edit: [Here is a good introduction](http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) to URL Rewriting.

Answer (score 5):

Variables passed in the form of a URL are called the [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).  In a url like:

```
 http://examples.com?a=b&c=d&e=f
```

The query string is ?a=b&c=d&e=f

In the Stackoverflow example, it uses URL Rewriting, specifically with [MVC Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) to make 'pretty URLs'.  There are other ways to do it in other languages.  Some make use of Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) ([example](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)) while others parse the requested URI.  In PHP a url like

```
 http://example.com/index.php/test/path/info
```

can be parsed by reading $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] which is /text/path/info.

Generally, they are using URL Rewriting to simulate the query string however.  In the Stackoverflow example:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698711/what-is-the-name-for-that-thing-that-lets-part-of-the-url-be-an-argument
```

The important parts are the **questions/698711**.  You can change the title of the question with impunity but the other two parts you cannot.

Comment: That seems to be specific for the kind I don't want

Comment: that seems harsh to mod down someone who was trying to help you? i would have just ignored and given no points if it wasnt helpful to you. But it is your quesiton.

Comment: He answered a question I said I was not asking. Now he has info that is useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually called the 'path info'.

Answer (score 1):

That's just URL mapping. It lets you use pretty URLs instead of a large query string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the StackOverflow URL works that way because it is using MVC whereas your bottom example is using standard requests.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed done by URL rewriting.

Usually, web application frameworks do this automatically if you install it correctly on your server.

Check out [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a URL parameter and uses the [HTTP GET method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). As others mentioned, it can be rewritten using URL rewriting so that the URL is easier to read and use. Some search keywords: "SEF URLs", "Apache Rewrite", "pretty URLs".